# Determining Laurent Expansion for $\left(1+z^2\right)^{-1/2}$ around the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm a bit confused about this one. Since $f$ has branch points at $z=\pm\dot{\imath}$ (which are therefore non-isolated singularities), there seem to be (at least?) two cases to consider here.

- When the branch cut is drawn so as to wholly be exterior to the region $\left|z\right|<1$. Here, the Laurent series degenerates to a MacLaurin expansion and can be easily computed to be something like $f\left(z\right) = 1-\dfrac{1}{2}z^2+\dfrac{3}{8}z^4+\cdots$. Further, this would be valid only $\left|z\right|<1$.
- The other case is when the branch cut could be wholly contained within $\left|z\right|<1$. I'm not sure how I could determine the Laurent expansion for this case (i.e. one that would be valid for $1<\left|z\right|<\infty$). Assuming that the contour of integration required for computing the coefficients is simply one that encloses the origin and is contained in the region of validity, then wouldn't that enclose $\pm\dot{\imath}$ as well? But these are supposedly non-isolated singularities so the residue theorem can't even be applied. Or do the singularities themselves need not be *within* the region of validity for them to be relevant? If the latter statement is true then that would imply that in fact all the coefficients in the Laurent expansion for $1<\left|z\right|<\infty$ vanish, no?

What am I missing here? An extended question is that would it not be possible to draw a branch cut that is sort of both interior and exterior to $\left|z\right|<1$? I don't see what's stopping that from happening but if that is the case, there would be an infinite number of annuli where an expansion could be made, no? Where the inner radius would be $\mathrm{max}\left(\left|z_0-0\right|\right)$ for $z_0$ on the branch cut?

Apologies if this seems like a jumble of ideas - just trying to wrap my head around what's happening here...

Comment: I don't understand how all these complicated thougths correspond to your very simple title.

Comment: the branch cuts of the argument function can be arbitrarily complex non-crossing curves that start from zero, usually its taken that branch cut of the non-positive ray of $\mathbb{C}$, in this case $(1+z^2)^{-1/2}$ is holomorphic in $|z|<1$ as you saw

Comment: @Masacroso So then it is true, that we can theoretically have infinitely many Laurent expansions, each valid for a unique region? How would I go about dealing with the second case?